# Realm: join two RealmObject by key

Tags: android, realm

I have two `RealmObject` models.

**Category**

```
public class Category extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private int categoryId;
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(int categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }


}
```

**Event**

```
public class Event extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private int eventId;
    private String title;
    private Category category;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getEventId() {
        return eventId;
    }

    public void setEventId(int eventId) {
        this.eventId = eventId;
    }

    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }
}
```

I get data from web service using two different requests:

**Categories response**

```
  [
        {
            "categoryId": 1,
            "name": "Category 1"
        },  
        {
            "categoryId": 2,
            "name": "Category 2"
        }
        ...
    ]
```

**Events response**

```
[
    {
        "eventId": 0,
        "title": "Event 0",
        "category": {
            "categoryId": 1,
            "name": null            
          }
    },
    {
        "eventId": 1,
        "title": "Event 1",
        "category": {
            "categoryId": 2,
            "name": null            
          }
    }
]
```

So, after mapping and saving data I get all `categories`

```
realm.where(Category.class).findAll();
```

return some `categories`

```
//0
categoryId = 0
name = "Category 0"

//1
categoryId = 1
name = "Category 1"


//2
categoryId = 2
name = "Category 2"


//3
categoryId = 3
name = "Category 3"
```

Get all `events`

```
realm.where(Event.class).findAll();
```

return some `events`

```
//0
Event = [{eventId:0},{title:Event 0},{category:[{categoryId:1},{name:null}]}]

eventId = 0
title = "Event 0"
category = {
  categoryId = 1
  name = null
}

//1
Event = [{eventId:1},{title:Event 1},{category:[{categoryId:2},{name:null}]}]

eventId = 1
title = "Event 1"
category = {
  categoryId = 2
  name = null
}
```

Field `Name` in `Category` is null. So, how can I get other `category` fields (name)? I thought `Realm` returns full category object, but doesn't. I need some like to `sql join`? It possible without changes models structure?

Comment: In your event response, the `Category.name` is `null` . That is the reason after it stored, the name field is null. Can you ask the server to change? Realm will update the name to `null` if it is `null` in the response. If you expect Realm ignore some fields when updating, just remove the corresponding field from the JSON response.

Comment: you're right, if remove field name from the json and save event as Category category = realm.createOrUpdateObjectFromJson(Category.class, "{\"categoryId\": 1}"); event.setCategory(category); it will work.

Comment: because it will check field name if (json.has("name")) then update name, but if update from object then name will null (default value) and it will update name in db

Comment: Yes! So the best way would be ask the server to remove the `name` if it doesn't need to be updated. Or workaround to remove the field from JSON before send it to `copyOrUpdateFromJson` .